# How to change the frequency of PIC internal oscillator?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, oscillator

Internal oscillator of [PIC16f884](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en026564) doesn't change frequency in the following code:

```
#pragma config BOREN=0,IESO=0,FOSC=INTRC_NOCLKOUT,MCLRE=1,WDTE=0,CP=1,LVP=0

volatile unsigned char counter = 0;
void setup( void )
{
  ANSEL = 0x00; // all digital
  TRISD  = 0x00; // all RD is output


// 
OSCCONbits.IRCF2 = 0;
OSCCONbits.IRCF1 = 0;
OSCCONbits.IRCF0 = 0;
OSCCONbits.SCS = 1;

while(!OSCCONbits.HTS);

//interrupt timer0
IRCF0 = 1;
IRCF1 = 1;
IRCF2 = 1;

}
```

No matter what values I assign to `OSCCONbits.IRCFx` the clock speed (as measured with a blinky light) never changes... The only other way that this could seem to behave this way, is if `_delay` were to somehow adjust for constant time rather than clicks, but I don't think that is the case.

EDIT: I am dumb...

why doesn't this work

```
int i = 0;
int *p = &i;
i = 0 // no matter what i change this to i is always one.... dumb
*p=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am so dumb, I had set the Oscillator speed in a different part of code right after it, using the shortened syntax...

`&(OSCCONbits.IRCF0) == &IRCF0`